# How to automatically add IDs to headings using functions.php in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am wondering how I could implement unique IDs for each heading element in a post (excluding pages) in Wordpress. That is, if two headings are identical, they should get different IDs. The IDs should also be descriptive. A dashed version of the actual title text is great.

I have found this code online:

```
// This function adds nice anchor with id attribute to our h2 tags for reference
// @link: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3

function anchor_content_h2($content) {

    // Pattern that we want to match
    $pattern = '/<h2>(.*?)</h2>/';

    // now run the pattern and callback function on content
    // and process it through a function that replaces the title with an id 
    $content = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) {
                $title = $matches[1];
                $slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes($title);
                return '<h2 id="' . $slug . '">' . $title . '</h2>';
            }, $content);
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'anchor_content_h2');
```

My concern here is that two identical headings will get the same ID. It also only works for H2-elements. Is there a better way to do what I want, or is this kind of thing generally not smart to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do this but if you use the post_name, you'll end up with a unique, dashed and descriptive value.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post#Member_Variables_of_WP_Post

If it were me, I would likely throw the code below into the respective template file.

```
the_title( '<h2 class="' . get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() ) . '">', '</h2>'  );
```

**EDIT** - So each h2 isn't tied to a post? You could just append $slug with a unique ID.

```
$slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes($title) . '-' . uniqid();
```

Comment: I am not sure that this is what I want to do. My goal is to have every H2-heading in a post have it's own unique and descriptive ID. I don't see how this will help in doing that? What am I missing here?

Comment: Ah, to have the mind of a programmer. Thanks, that will work. Feeling kind of stupid, but I'll go for it :)

Answer (score 0):

Changed the function so that it works with all levels of headings (h1-h6).

```
function dt_anchor_content_h1_h6 ($content) {
    // Pattern that we want to match
    $pattern = "~<h(1|2|3|4|5|6)[^>]*>(.*?)</h(1|2|3|4|5|6)>~";

    // now run the pattern and callback function on content
    // and process it through a function that replaces the title with an id
    $content = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) {
        $title = $matches[2];
        $slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes($title);
        return "<h{$matches[1]} id='$slug-" . uniqid() ."'>" . $title . "</h{$matches[1]}>";
    }, $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'dt_anchor_content_h1_h6');
```